# SetState does not update immediately

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm new to flutter and I'm having a problem here.

I'm developing an application to schedule meals and I wanted that when he got to the widget to confirm the appointments the calendar would appear gray and disabled

Booking Area widget

```
import 'package:app/widgets/booking/datepicker.dart';
import 'package:app/widgets/booking/pageone.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

bool confirmationPage = false;

class BookingArea extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookingArea({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BookingAreaState createState() => _BookingAreaState();
}

class _BookingAreaState extends State<BookingArea> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 600,
            height: 350,
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: const PageOne(),
          ),
          Container(
            foregroundDecoration: confirmationPage
                ? const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.saturation,
                  )
                : null,
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            child: const DatePicker(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Confirmation Page widget

```
import 'package:app/widgets/booking/booking_area.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageOne extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageOneState createState() => _PageOneState();
}

class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      confirmationPage = true;
    });
    return const Center(
      child: Text("Pagina 1"),
    );
  }
}
```

what happens is that when I give the setState on PageOne it only applies the state (changes the widget color) when I "restart" the page through routes.

What I wanted was that when he got to page one he would immediately change the color of the calendar

sorry for bad english

Thanks :)

Comment: you have declared `confirmationPage` as a global variable then you are trying to update its state. this is not the right way. please refer to official flutter docs on the local state in the flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are only updating your `PageOne` with this `setState((){})` call.

It doesn't rebuild the parent widget.

This would be the quick solution, but I would highly recommend looking for a sophisticated statemanagement solution

```dart
import 'package:app/widgets/booking/datepicker.dart';
import 'package:app/widgets/booking/pageone.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BookingArea extends StatefulWidget {
  const BookingArea({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BookingAreaState createState() => _BookingAreaState();
}

class _BookingAreaState extends State<BookingArea> {

  bool confirmationPage = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 600,
            height: 350,
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: PageOne(onInit:() {
              setState((){
                confirmation = true;
              });
            }),
          ),
          Container(
            foregroundDecoration: confirmationPage
                ? const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.saturation,
                  )
                : null,
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            child: const DatePicker(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
import 'package:app/widgets/booking/booking_area.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PageOne extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageOne({Key? key, required this.onInit}) : super(key: key);
  final VoidCallback onInit;
  @override
  _PageOneState createState() => _PageOneState();
}

class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      widget.onInit();
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text("Pagina 1"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I got it. I have another question, and if I selected an option on PageOne, and after validations, it returned another question widget called PageTwo, and I wanted to make the DatePicker gray only on PageTwo, is the procedure the same or does something change?

Comment: In general, you need to consider which widget you want to rebuild. Setstate need to get called there.